# How to handle large numbers of redirects for dynamic pages with optional slugs, in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, vercel

My site has a few dynamic routes that result in thousands of hydrated pages. The pages follow a url structure like: `/artists/[id]/[slug]` or `/concerts/[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug]`. Currently, my page structure mimics those routes: `/pages/artists/[id]/[slug].tsx` and `/pages/concerts/[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug].tsx`.

The route with slug is preferred, but the site should gracefully redirect when the slug is not available. For example, I would like to have any request going to `/artist/id` be redirected to `/artist/id/slug`. And likewise, I'd like to do some redirecting for various parts of the concerts urls.

I originally tried specifying the redirects in next.config.js like:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  async redirects() {
    const [allArtists, allConcerts] = await Promise.all([...]);
    return [
      ...allArtists.map((artist) => {
        return {
          source: `/artists/${artist.id}`,
          destination: `/artists/${artist.id}/${slugify(artist.name)}`,
          permanent: false,
        };
      }),
      ...allConcerts.map((concert) => {
        return {
          source: `/concerts/${concert.year}`,
          destination: `/tours/${concert.year}`,
          permanent: false,
        };
      }),
      ...allConcerts.map((concert) => {
        return {
          source: `/concerts/${concert.year}/${concert.month}`,
          destination: `/tours/${concert.year}`,
          permanent: false,
        };
      }),
      ...allConcerts.map((concert) => {
        return {
          source: `/concerts/${concert.year}/${concert.month}/${concert.day}`,
          destination: `/concerts/${concert.year}/${concert.month}/${concert.day}/${slugify(concert.name)}`,
          permanent: false,
        };
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

However, as of today, vercel/next.js does not support more than 1,000 redirects specified in that file.

I tried to return `redirect: pathWithSlug` from `getStaticProps`, but get the following error:

```
Error: `redirect` can not be returned from getStaticProps during prerendering
```

Any ideas or approaches for how I can accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> vercel/next.js does not support more than 1,000 redirects specified in that file.

You weren't [kidding](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/redirects), this is something important to consider before moving into the platform. Some ideas & compromise:

- Use `getServerSideProps` for `pages/artists/[id]` and [use redirect there](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)
- Use the same content for `pages/artists/[id]` as `pages/artists/[id]/[slug]`, but set canonical url to avoid SEO penalty

Answer (score 1):

First, you could significantly reduce the number of entries for the `/concerts/*` to `/tours/*` redirects by using path matching.

```js
async redirects() {
    return [
        // ...
        {
            source: '/concerts/:year/:month',
            destination: '/tours/:year',
            permanent: false
        },
        {
            source: '/concerts/:year',
            destination: '/tours/:year',
            permanent: false
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, the same cannot be done for the other paths. This alone could potentially reduce the number of entries below 1000 - depending on the amount of artists/concerts you have - but sooner or later it would become a problem again.

Second, to address the remaining paths, I would convert your `/artists/[id]/[slug]` and `/concerts/[year]/[month]/[day]/[slug]` routes into dynamic [catch-all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes):

- `/artists/[...slug]`
- `/concerts/[...slug]`

This would allow the `/concerts/[...slug].tsx` page to match both `/concerts/2020/08/20` *and* `/concerts/2020/08/20/concert-name` URLs, meaning you wouldn't need a redirect for these pages at all. The same would apply for the `artists/*` routes.

As @DerekNguyen mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66523862/1870780), having a canonical URL that would be used in both for SEO purposes would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping for an approach other than a catch-all route. The catch-all page kind of defeats the purpose of the routing infrastructure and I'm not sure it offers much over having `pages/artists/[id]/index.tsx` return content with only meta refresh and canonical link tags.